# Unable to successfuly deploy Blazor work on IIS

Tags: iis, blazor, webassembly

I am trying to deploy my Blazor WA to my local IIS, I have already deployed other .net core 3.1 API  to another site locally.  I have also successfully deployed the Blazor App to Azure Blob storage static website. From VS 2019 I click publish and it successfully publishes the file to the selected folder.
when I navigate to the url http://localhost:6989 I get 404 not found.  I have followed the steps required from multiple locations
https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-deploy-a-blazor-application-on-iis/
[image]
Here are the things I've changes in the site. not much has changed:
[image]
Web.cong settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You have to edit the question to reveal your IIS settings.

Comment: there are many IIS Settings which ones?

Comment: I believe you didn't touch every IIS settings to create a site for this Blazor app, so reveal all those you touched please. For example, site bindings https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: Ok I've added those changes. I didn't include them because these are standard settings

Comment: I just did some testing, but couldn't reproduce the issue. How exactly did you create the project? My `web.config` looks completely different, and has the proper URL rewrite rules.

Comment: What error message did you see when you access index.html?  Besides, have you implemented rewrite rule for your blazor WA aapplication？

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the comment. I used your comment to discover why my web.config was wrong. I had Some wrong versions of the assembles  and I guess it wasn't acting nicely. I cleaned up the project and make sure I was using v3.2 and the web.config was generated properly

Comment: You might post your findings as an answer and accept it. That should help others more.

Answer (score 0):

@LexLi Thanks for the comment. I used your comment to discover why my web.config was wrong. I had Some wrong versions of the assembles and I guess it wasn't acting nicely. I cleaned up the project and make sure I was using v3.2 and the web.config was generated properly